# Size of Controls in UserControls

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

In my application I have several `UserControl`s. One is for Displaying all persons. Therefor I have the following `UserControl` which is displayed in the content-part of my MainWindow:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ScM.Contents.View.PersonssView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:ScM.Contents.ViewModel"
             xmlns:view="clr-namespace:ScM.Contents.View"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <viewModel:PersonsViewModel />
    </UserControl.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <view:PersonsTreeView Grid.Column="0" Margin="2"
                         OpenPerson="{Binding DataContext.OpenPersonCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}"
                         Persons="{Binding DataContext.Persons, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
        RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}" />
    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Width="2" ShowsPreview="True" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,2" />
        <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" Grid.Column="2"  Margin="2">
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentContent, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" MinWidth="400"/>
        </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

If the users clicks on a `TreeViewItem` in the PersonsTreeView another `UserControl` should be displayed in the `ContentControl`.

The `UserControl` to display in the `ContentControl` is called PersonView and looks like

```
 <UserControl x:Class="ScM.Contents.View.PersonView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:ScM.Contents.ViewModel"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <viewModel:PersonViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
<TabControl>
        <TabItem Header="Personal">
            <GroupBox Header="Name">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="Firstname:"/>
                    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"></TextBox>
                    <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="Lastname:"/>
                    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"></TextBox>                
                </Grid>
            </GroupBox>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
```

My problem now is, that the Controls in the PersonView are very small (so as ther were AutoSize). I thought they would be * (maximum).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When resizing user control in designer it sometimes changes `d:Width` (and height) to `Width`.

Comment: @Sinatr, that is totally incorrect. `d:Width` has absolutely no relation to the `Width` property of any controls. The [`mc:Ignorable` attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa350024(v=vs.110).aspx) *Specifies which XML namespace prefixes encountered in a markup file may be ignored by a XAML processor*. Therefore, `d:Width` is ***ignored** by the XAML processor*.

Comment: @Tomtom, if you want any serious answers, you'll have to provide more information... *My problem now is, that the Controls in the PersonView are very small* is a terrible description of your problem and the obvious answer would be *make them bigger*.

Comment: @Sheridan, I wrote what happens to me, sometimes resizing control in designer changes `Width` instead of `d:Width`, then upon displaying this control somewhere it suddenly become small, because it has `Width` specified. You see? I could provide an answer with screenshot, because I feel that would be exactly the case: @Tomtom might *auto-size* user controls (to see them better when designing user control itself), it gets `Width` and this width is used when displaying control (while expected behavior is to have it stretched horizontally/vertically)

Comment: Well. I'm expecting that the ContentControl takes the complete remaining space.

Comment: @Tomtom, do you specify `Width` and/or `Height` in your control *accidentally* (or with help of designer ^^)? Your xaml is not complete.

Comment: could you post a screen of what you see and what you expect?

Comment: You are missing a RowDefinition in your first xaml markup code. I'm confused why are you dealing with TreeViewItems here? And as both Sinatr and Sheridan is stating the d:x attributes are just used for designmode. Your code seems incomplete and it's hard to tell without seeing "it all".

Comment: I've updated the Question and added the UserControl-Definitions